# Delete a node in a linked list using only 1 local pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Exercise excerpt from the book "C Programming: A Modern Approach" by K.N King. I ask for help in understanding if the last part of my solution is incorrect.

> Modify the delete_from_list function so that it uses only one pointer variable instead of two (cur and prev).

This is a simple linked list and the function deletes the first node encountered whose `.value` is equal to the argument `n`.

Original code:

```
struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *delete_from_list(struct node *list, int n)
{
    struct node *cur, *prev;

    for (cur = list, prev = NULL;
         cur != NULL && cur->value != n;
         prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
        ;
    if (cur == NULL)
        return list;
    if (prev == NULL)
        list = list->next;
    else
        prev->next = cur->next;
    free(cur);
    return list;
}
```

My solution:

```
struct node *delete_from_list(struct node **list, int n) {
    struct node *ptr = *list;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr->value == n) {
            *list = ptr->next;
            free(ptr);
            break;
        }
        list = &(ptr->next);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return *list;
}
```

I think this solution is almost correct, but I struggle to understand if the last statement, `return *list;`, actually returns the beginning of the list. This is my first time using a pointer to a pointer to a struct, so I may be misunderstanding some concept.

I'm more interested in knowing how my solution is incorrect or not, than being given a completely different solution, so as to save your time.

Comment: To help you visualize the list and the operations and what happens, I suggest you use a pencil and some paper. Draw a simple list, using labeled boxes for the nodes and other variables and arrows for all pointers (including links). Then walk through the code line by line, erasing and redrawing arrows as you perform operations on the pointers.

Comment: You're not returning the head of the list after the removal, you're returning the node after the removed node in the list and modifying the head "in place" if it needs to change.  This is fine as long as you don't expect something else to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed the `list` parameter to be a pointer to the caller's `node*` variable that is pointing at the head `node` of the linked list. That change in itself is fine (but not part of the exercise, FYI):

```
          +------+    +------+
[head] -> | node | -> | node | -> ...
   ^      +------+    +------+
   |      
[list]
```

By using a pointer-to-pointer as the input parameter, there is no longer any reason to `return` a `node*` pointer to the head `node`, since you can just modify the input `node*` variable to point at the new head `node`.

If your loop finds the `n` value in the list, you are trying to do exactly that update. However, you are modifying the input `node*` variable *unconditionally* to now point at the next `node` which follows the removed `node`.

That works fine if the removed `node` is the 1st `node` in the list:

```
   +---------------+
   |     +------+  |   +------+
[head]   | xxxx |  +-> | node | -> ...
   ^     +------+      +------+
   |         ^
[list]     FREED!
```

But it is not OK if the removed `node` is not the 1st `node`. You will corrupt your list by losing access to all of the `node`s that preceded the removed `node`:

```
   +----------------------------+
   |      +------+    +------+  |   +------+
[head]    | node | -> | xxxx |  +-> | node | -> ...
   ^      +------+    +------+      +------+
   |         ^            ^
[list]     LEAKED!      FREED!
```

You are not performing that safely check, as the original code does.

So, try something more like this instead:

```
void free_node(struct node **n)
{
    struct node *next = (*n)->next;
    free(*n);
    *n = next;
}

void delete_from_list(struct node **list, int n) {
    while (*list != NULL) {
        if ((*list)->value == n) {
            *list = free_node(*list);
            // or: free_node(list);
            break;
        }
        list = &((*list)->next);
    }
}
```

On the 1st loop iteration, `list` points at the caller's `node*` variable which is pointing at the list:

```
          +------+    +------+
[head] -> | node | -> | node | -> ...
   ^      +------+    +------+
   |      
[list]
```

If that 1st `node` is removed, the caller's `node*` variable is updated to point at the next `node` following the removed `node`, and the function exits:

```
   +---------------+
   |     +------+  |   +------+
[head]   | xxxx |  +-> | node | -> ...
   ^     +------+      +------+
   |         ^
[list]     FREED!
```

Otherwise, on the next loop iteration, `list` is now pointing at the previous `node`'s `next` field. If that next `node` is removed, the previous `node`'s `next` field is updated to point at the next `node` following the removed `node`, and the function exits:

```
              +-----------------+
              |                 |
          +------+    +------+  |   +------+
[head] -> | node |    | xxxx |  +-> | node | -> ...
          +------+    +------+      +------+
              ^           ^
              |         FREED!
[list] -------+
```

As so on, repeating until the entire linked list has been iterated through.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/rdKDA4)

---

Now, if changing the signature of the `delete_from_list()` function is not an option (because the exercise didn't ask you to do that), then you can do this instead, with the same effect:

```
struct node* delete_from_list(struct node *list, int n) {
    struct node **ptr = &list;
    while (*ptr != NULL) {
        if ((*ptr)->value == n) {
            *ptr = free_node(*ptr);
            // or: free_node(ptr);
            break;
        }
        ptr = &((*ptr)->next);
    }
    return list;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/fC76t0)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of late but I was recently struggling with this same exact exercise. I think Remy gave a very good and detailed answer however I just wanted to share my solution. Since the problem said modify the function I wanted to keep the prototype the same and have it always return the beginning of the list.

```
struct node *delete_from_list(struct node *list, int n)
{
    if (!list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (list->value == n)
    {
        struct node *temp = list->next;
        free(list);
        return temp;
    }
    else
    {
        list->next = delete_from_list(list->next, n);
        return list;
    }
}
```

By using recursion I was able to eliminate the need for the extra pointer because the function will always return the next node that does not contain the first instance of n. This guarantees it works for the first node and any other node as well. This allows me to use just one pointer to help with the free() call.

And although this works I am still not sure if it's within the "spirit" of the problem because we have not gone over much recursion yet in the book and also I think I am technically using as many local variables as there are nodes in the list because again it's recursive.

This was a really hard problem and I don't think King gave enough info and context around the problem or at least over estimated our ability to approach it soundly at this point in the book.